# Why does vertical scrollbar not allow scrolling?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a long list of buttons and labels within a vertical stackpanel contained within a border in a grid. I can't get a vertical scrollbar to work with my stackpanel. So I added it to the grid that contains the stackpanel, but the scrollbar offers no way to scroll. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a picture of the list and the scrollbar.

[image]

Here is the code:

````
            Grid.SetRow(leftPanelBorder, 1);
            statsDrawGrid.Children.Add(leftPanelBorder);

            Grid.SetRow(leftStackPanel, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(leftStackPanel, 0);
            leftPanelBorder.Child = leftStackPanel;

            //Draw the reservoir list
            InitializeTheReservoirs();
            DrawTheReservoirList(leftStackPanel, (string)byNameMenu.Header);

            //Add a vertical scrollbar
            ScrollViewer scrollBar = new ScrollViewer();
            scrollBar.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
            Grid.SetRow(scrollBar, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(scrollBar, 0);
            statsDrawGrid.Children.Add(scrollBar);

            statsDrawGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
            statsWindow.Content = statsDrawGrid;
            statsWindow.Show();```
````

Comment: Well two things.... One you are doing your UI in code rather than XAML.... And two you need to set an explicit Height to the container.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I do not use XAML ever. Since I code dynamic seismic and well log data I prefer to do things dynamically in the code. I'm not sure what you mean by the container, but I added this:`statsDrawGrid.Height = 1000;` but that did not change the behavior...

Comment: Your `scrollbar` does not have any content that it could scroll. If I had to guess, you probably want to set `leftPanelBorder` as the `scrollbar`'s `Child`.

Comment: The `Grid.Row/Column` are absolutely necessary. When I just commented them out all the buttons/labels were crammed up in the top row/left column obscuring the menu. The `grid` contains the` border` which provides a simple light grey background around the `stackpanel` that contains the `buttons/labels`.  I'm new to this forum and am not sure how I can minimize the code and still make it legible? Perhaps I don't understand what you are asking in this regard.

Comment: @Nico Schertler - that did it! But scrollbar has no `Child` or `Children.Add` so I had to do it this way `scrollBar.Content = leftPanelBorder;`

Comment: @Darkonekt there is _no_ rule that states that you must use XAML.  For dynamic UIs such as the OPs, you must use code

Comment: @MickyD you can make your screen dynamic using XAML and bindings.... Creating the UI using C# pretty much defeats the purpose of using WPF.  There is nothing you can't achieve using proper WPF, Styling and Bindings that could achieve using just C#....

Comment: @Darkonekt - I have not yet learned about binding...you give me motivation to keep learning so I can do exactly what you said. I don't use Forms, I use WPF knowing I will use binding once I learn how to do so. Do you have reference material from which I could learn?

Comment: @Darkonekt incorrect. That isn't the meaning of dynamic.   XAML requires you to define every conceivable _object type_ combination possible with data templates ahead of time.  C# merely requires code for a single _value type_ making it infinitely more re-usable and adaptable.  This is exactly how every single property grid works.  Additionaly _"binding"_ is not solely owned by XAML-authored UIs nor has it anything to do with _"dynamic"_ or _adaptable_ UIs.  I always use XAML except for when dynamic is required

Comment: @MickyD if you had your UI in XAML you could change the C# and the model and not have to change a single line of UI... The power of WPF IS XAML... otherwise why bother using WPF?? Why not just use Win Forms?  Separating the presentation layer from the model is a widely recognized pattern in the industry for example MVC, MVVM etc.... Hardcoding your UI in C# on the other hand is clearly an anti pattern.

Comment: @Darkonekt I saw this which implies a limitation using XAML? Any comment?

https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/844786-wpf-underline-text-label-c

Comment: @Darkonekt we are talking about `dynamic` UI.   BTW, there is zero rule that states that one _must_ use MVVM too

Comment: @MickyD you simply do not understand.... There is no rules when programming other than the compiler.... That does not mean one should not use INDUSTRY standards and patterns....  And once again you do not understand WPF... XAML is even more dynamic than hardcoding your C# UI.... That is the whole point of separating the Presentation Layer from your Logic... That is the whole purpose of existence of WPF Windows PRESENTATION Foundation... Using WPF without XAML is an anti pattern.. There is NOTHING you can do in C# that I cannot do in XAML....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what FINALLY worked. My thanks to @Nico Schertler!!

```
            //Add a vertical scrollbar
            ScrollViewer scrollBar = new ScrollViewer();
            scrollBar.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
            Grid.SetRow(scrollBar, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(scrollBar, 0);
            statsDrawGrid.Children.Add(scrollBar);

            //Draw the container/border
            Border leftPanelBorder = new Border();
            Grid.SetColumn(leftPanelBorder, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(leftPanelBorder, 1);
            scrollBar.Content = leftPanelBorder;

            Grid.SetRow(leftStackPanel, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(leftStackPanel, 0);
            leftPanelBorder.Child = leftStackPanel;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the scrollbar before creating and filling-up the left stack panel:

```
Grid.SetRow(leftPanelBorder, 1);
statsDrawGrid.Children.Add(leftPanelBorder);

//Add a vertical scrollbar
ScrollViewer scrollBar = new ScrollViewer();
scrollBar.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
Grid.SetRow(scrollBar, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(scrollBar, 0);
statsDrawGrid.Children.Add(scrollBar);

Grid.SetRow(leftStackPanel, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(leftStackPanel, 0);
leftPanelBorder.Child = leftStackPanel;

//Draw the reservoir list
InitializeTheReservoirs();
DrawTheReservoirList(leftStackPanel, (string)byNameMenu.Header);

statsDrawGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
statsWindow.Content = statsDrawGrid;
statsWindow.Show();
```

Comment: Yes indeed, but I had to add one more line, the `scrollbar.Content=leftPanelBorder`!

Answer (score 0):

You added the `ScrollViewer` to the grid but it's empty, thus the scrollbar appears (due the forced visibility) but it has no effect.

Move the `StackPanel` inside the `ScrollViewer`, instead:

```
        Grid.SetRow(leftPanelBorder, 1);
        statsDrawGrid.Children.Add(leftPanelBorder);

        Grid.SetRow(leftStackPanel, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(leftStackPanel, 0);
        //leftPanelBorder.Child = leftStackPanel;  <-- NOTE

        //Draw the reservoir list
        InitializeTheReservoirs();
        DrawTheReservoirList(leftStackPanel, (string)byNameMenu.Header);

        //Add a vertical scrollbar
        ScrollViewer scrollBar = new ScrollViewer();
        scrollBar.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        Grid.SetRow(scrollBar, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(scrollBar, 0);
        statsDrawGrid.Children.Add(scrollBar);
        scrollBar.Child = leftStackPanel;      // <-- NOTE

        statsDrawGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
        statsWindow.Content = statsDrawGrid;
        statsWindow.Show();
```

I didn't try, but it should work.

As a suggestion, this way to build a hierarchical composition of UI is rather hard to read. XAML has the primary goal to improve the readiness and editing of the code.

You can do almost everything via XAML: there are few things you must do via C#.

Comment: I am admittedly new to C# and programming. I started using XAML following the Headfirst C# manual, but then it just seemed lazy/too easy...perhaps I like flogging myself...then I couldn't figure out how I would dynamically add multiple log curves when I read a well log and draw them using XAML, so I switched to doing it ALL in code...perhaps I should take the time to become a XAML expert?!

Comment: @JW there is nothing wrong nor is there any rule that you _must_ use XAML.  In fact, for dynamic UIs such as yours, doing so via code is the way to go

Comment: Some sort of itemscontrol and item templating is the first candidate for showing multiples of anything. The recommended way of creating totally dynamic ui is to build xaml as a string and xamlreader.parse it into ui objects. This has the substantial benefit that you can take what your code generates and paste it into a scratch view, see what happens.